# Select HTML elements by the name of their first child element

Tags: perl

I need to find the value if the `id` attribute of all `<div>` elements that have a `<span>` child.

For instance, given this HTML

```
<div id="a1">                 <span> xa1 </span>       </div>
<div id="a2"> <p>...</p>      <span> xa2 </span>       </div>
<div id="a3">            <p>  <span> xa3 </span> </p>  </div>
<div id="a4"> <p>...</p>                             </div>

<div id="b1"> </div>          <span> xb1 </span>
<div id="b2"> </div> <p>      <span> xb1 </span> </p>
<div id="b3"> </div> <p>.</p> <span> xb3 </span>
```

I need to get: `a1` and nothing more.

Because the CSS selectors haven't something like *positive-lookahead* I need to search the HTML somewhat incrementally, but I don't know how.

How to modify the next source, to get only `a1`?

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;

use Mojo::DOM;

my $html = do {local $/; <DATA>};

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($html);

for my $div ($dom->find('div')->each) {
   #say "DIV[[$div]]";
   my @spans = $div->find('div > span')->each;   #found a1 and a2 ;(
   say $div->attr('id') if (@spans == 1);
}

__DATA__
<div id="a1">                 <span> xa1 </span>       </div>
<div id="a2"> <p>...</p>      <span> xa2 </span>       </div>
<div id="a3">            <p>  <span> xa3 </span> </p>  </div>
<div id="a4"> <p>...</p>                             </div>

<div id="b1"> </div>          <span> xb1 </span>
<div id="b2"> </div> <p>      <span> xb1 </span> </p>
<div id="b3"> </div> <p>.</p> <span> xb3 </span>

<p id="p1">                <span> xp1 </span>       </p>
<p id="p2"> <p>...</p>     <span> xp2 </span>       </p>
<p id="p3">            <p> <span> xp3 </span> </p>  </p>
<p id="p4"> <p>...</p>                              </p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the element you're looking for in a slightly roundabout way using css-style selectors and Mojo::DOM's [`parent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM#parent) method:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature ":5.10";
use Mojo::DOM;

my $html = do{ local $/; <DATA>};

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($html);

# searches for div elements with spans as the first child
for my $div ( $dom->find('div > span:first-child')->parent->each ) {
    say "id: " . $div->attr('id') if $div->attr('id');
}

__DATA__
<div id="a1">                 <span> xa1 </span>       </div>
<div id="a2"> <p>...</p>      <span> xa2 </span>       </div>
<div id="a3">            <p>  <span> xa3 </span> </p>  </div>
<div id="a4"> <p>...</p>                             </div>

<div id="b1"> </div>          <span> xb1 </span>
<div id="b2"> </div> <p>      <span> xb1 </span> </p>
<div id="b3"> </div> <p>.</p> <span> xb3 </span>

<p id="p1">                <span> xp1 </span>       </p>
<p id="p2"> <p>...</p>     <span> xp2 </span>       </p>
<p id="p3">            <p> <span> xp3 </span> </p>  </p>
<p id="p4"> <p>...</p>                              </p>
```

Output:

```
id: a1
```

Or if you know that it's just the first such div that you want, then the following would work:

```
say "id: " . $dom->at('div > span:first-child')->parent->attr('id');
```

Comment: YES! I somewhat overlooked the `first-child` and `nth-child`.. Thanx. Accpept this, because it is Mojo::DOM solution what I already know (somewhat).

Answer (score 3):

It is unfortunate that `Mojo::DOM` doesn't support XPath expressions as well as CSS, as it's a very natural expression in the former.

You may want to consider switching to [`HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath). The code would look like this. It uses the XPath expression

```
//div[*][local-name(*[1])="span"]/@id
```

which asks for the `id` attribute of any `div` element in the document that has at least one child and the local name of the first child is `span`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.014;

use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $tree = do {
   local $/;
   HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content(<DATA>);
};

say for $tree->findvalues('//div[*][local-name(*[1])="span"]/@id');

__DATA__
<html><body>
<div id="a1">                 <span> xa1 </span>       </div>
<div id="a2"> <p>...</p>      <span> xa2 </span>       </div>
<div id="a3">            <p>  <span> xa3 </span> </p>  </div>
<div id="a4"> <p>...</p>                             </div>

<div id="b1"> </div>          <span> xb1 </span>
<div id="b2"> </div> <p>      <span> xb1 </span> </p>
<div id="b3"> </div> <p>.</p> <span> xb3 </span>

<p id="p1">                <span> xp1 </span>       </p>
<p id="p2"> <p>...</p>     <span> xp2 </span>       </p>
<p id="p3">            <p> <span> xp3 </span> </p>  </p>
<p id="p4"> <p>...</p>                              </p>
</body></html>
```

**output**

```
a1
```

Comment: Thanx, but that prints `a1` and `a2` too. I want only `a1` as i said in the question.

Comment: @cajwine: I apologise. I just came across that when I was re-reading the question.

Comment: I prefer Mojo::DOM because it more closely matches jquery so I don't need to learn yet another format.

Comment: @marneborn: That's fair. The choice is really between CSS and XPath, and since CSS3 the choice is mostly personal preference, but it would have been nice to include both choices in `Mojo::DOM`

Answer (score 0):

Either this:

```
my @spans = $div->find('div > span:first-child')->each;
say $div->attr('id') if (@spans == 1);
```

Or this:

```
my @kids = $div->children;
say $div->attr('id') if @kids and $kids[0]->type eq 'span';
```